# Temporary Storage not working in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Here is my Temporary storage code which is inside the php and it is not working in the laravel Controller

This is inside a View :

```
echo "<script>localStorage.setItem('filename', 'key.pdf');</script>";   


$newval =  "<script>document.write(localStorage.filename);</script>";
Input::file('salesconformation')->move($destinationPath,$newval );
$desPathimg=public_path()."assets/uploads/home/".$newval;
```

I can't able to store the File,

While fetching the value of $newval and storing it, It shows the error

```
   Could not move the file "C:\xampp\tmp\phpAB6A.tmp" to "C:\xampp\htdocs\wrp\public/assets/uploads/home\script>" ()
```

What is the mistake i am doing ?

**Whether Laravel Don't support localstoage ??**

Comment: Where is `prettyPrint` used? It's not in the code you posted.

Comment: I even used pretty print lib as <script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js">

Comment: Well seems like that error is generate by some code trying to use `prettyPrint` but cannot find it so the issue is there.

Comment: Otherwise `localStorage` is a JS feature so Lavarel doesn't need to do anything to support it.

Comment: Sorry, prettyprint is not the problem. I have updated the error log

Comment: Nor is it with localStorage, seems to be with this line `Input::file('salesconformation')->move($destinationPath,$newval );` it's weird that the path it try to copy to use both slashes and backslashes and end with `>`.

Comment: Yes, the path its tries to copy seems to be wrong, I mean the $newval in the line Input::.. take the actual code inside the $newval, I don't know why it is not getting the local storage instead of taking its code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65582/discussion-between-biz-dev-and-gillesc).

Answer (score 0):

You can't run your js code inside this controller.

You should run localStorage processes in client-side, i didn't see any javascript compiler in php controller (may be possible but it may not for client side).

So then get $newVal(in your example this comes "document.write(localStorage.filename);" as a string so it fails) for file move process then your logic will success.